# SQL Join using iBatis

Tags: sql, join, ibatis

I have just started learning iBatis. I have learnt to code the basic CRUD operations. But when it comes to complex queries , I have no idea on how to implement them.

Please let me know how to implement the below mentioned SQL using iBatis

```
SELECT a.desc FROM AAA a,BBB b,CCC c WHERE a.no='0012AART' AND b.code=a.code AND b.type_id=c.type_id AND c.type_desc='yyyy' ORDER BY a.createTime DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The same as you do your select.

```
<select id="yourSelectName"
parameterType="HashMap"
>

SELECT a.desc FROM AAA a,BBB b,CCC c WHERE a.no= #{no} AND b.code=a.code AND b.type_id=c.type_id AND c.type_desc=#{year} ORDER BY a.createTime DESC;
</select>
```